# ServerShuttingDown is not a valid member of ServerStorage "ServerStorage"

Tags: roblox

I found an error saying [ServerShuttingDown is not a valid member of ServerStorage "ServerStorage"] on this line of code:
game.ServerStorage.ServerShuttingDown = false
ServerShuttingDown is a booleanvalue in ServerStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Any Value object, whether it's an [IntValue](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/IntValue), [BoolValue](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/BoolValue), [StringValue](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/StringValue), etc., they all have a `Value` property. If you want to update it, you need to set that value.

```
local boolValue = game.ServerStorage.ServerShuttingDown
boolValue.Value = false
```